# Launching multiple php pages/programs

Tags: php, cron, automation

I need to be able to fire off several php pages launched by a cron job.

At present I can fire off the first one by the cron job calling a php page that just has:

```
<?php

file_get_contents("http://whatever.com/.../sandbox/message_launcher.php");

?>
```

but how will I fire off:

```
file_get_contents("hxxp://whatever.tld/.../user01/message_launcher.php");
file_get_contents("hxxp://whatever.tld/.../user02/message_launcher.php");
```

etc? I need to do about 10 of these every 5 mins.

Grateful for any simple ideas. I am bumping along somewhat out of my depth.

TIA
Stve

Hi still finding my way on Stackoverflow but this seems to be the best way to post the solution.

I did do five consecutive file get contents and all is working fine. HOWEVER I suspect if we ever get an error in file number 1 then it will stop there. This is fine for an early alpha but I am pretty sure the is NOT robust.

This is on a godaddy cheapo Linux hosting plan and you can only launch a simple page call at each five minute cron point.

But as I said it works fine for now.

Comment: You could write a loop, and replace the specific parts of the URL.

Comment: How about calling that url with `wget` in the cron job? `wget -O - -q -t 1 hxxp://whatever.tld/.../user01/message_launcher.php` You can also wrap many `wget` calls in a bash script, using a loop or whatever. (I assume we are talking about a linux server.) This would be better, as you don't have to call PHP for such a simple task. It does not answer your question, but gives you a bit more efficient solution.